# $\max, \min$ relation for probability LP

Tags: analysis, probability-theory

Suppose we have 2 LPs; 
$$\text{maximize } c^T\mathbf{x}$$$$\text{subject to} \,A \mathbf{x}\geq0 $$ $$\sum  \mathbf{x}=1$$
$$\mathbf{x}\geq 0$$
and the other is,
$$\text{minimize } c^T\mathbf{x}$$$$\text{subject to} \,A \mathbf{x}\geq0 $$$$\sum  \mathbf{x}=1$$
$$\mathbf{x}\geq 0$$

on the same set of linear functions. Only difference is first one is to maximize other is to minimize the same linear function $c^T\mathbf{x}$, where $^T$ is the transpose. We also have $c \geq 0$. The variable vector $\mathbf{x}$ is probabilities.

Can we give a relation between the maximum and the minimum of $c^T\mathbf{x}$ in the feasibility region in terms of the coefficients? What is the the approach to do so?

For example how large can the difference be? 
$$\gamma \cdot\text{min }  c^T\mathbf{x} + \alpha< \text{max }c^T\mathbf{x} $$
where $\gamma$, $\alpha$ are constants.
Can we say something by $A$ and $c$?

Can we use the duals of the two problems to get a relation?

Or may be the maximum gain direction of $A$ with directional derivative of $c^T\mathbf{x}$?

Thank you.

PS. NOT home work

Comment: They can be vastly different. $\min \{ x | x \ge 0 \} $ and $\max \{ x | x \ge 0 \} $ will produce rather different results.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, but based on the coefficients can we come up with a relation? Thank you

Comment: I do not really get the point of the question. Can you say something about the optimal value of one single linear program "in terms of the coefficients" (whatever that means)?

Comment: @Dirk The feasible region is determined by $A$ and the "slope" of the function to optimize is determined by $c$ so I feel they somehow will provide bounds for the optimal values of min and max. I am not trying to find the optimal, just bounds. Thanks

Comment: I don't know the meaning of $Ax\geq0$. What is $A$ and if $A$ is a matrix then what does $\geq$ mean?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang $A$ is a matrix. It means each row of $Ax$ is greater than or equal to 0. Note $Ax$ is a column vector. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the constraint $\sum x_i = 1$ you have at least one bound:

$$\max c^Tx - \min c^Tx \leq 2\|c\|_\infty.$$

Saying more likely requires more information about the geometry of $c$, the cone $A$, and their relationship to the cone $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain a little more what you mean by geometry? May be I can provide more information then.

Comment: Is $c\geq 0$? And/or $Ac\geq 0$?

Comment: $c\geq 0$ but I don't think I can say $Ac \geq 0$. Thank you

Comment: Can we use maximum gain direction of $A$?